# Return response from class in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm creating a service that creates a new customer in Magento 2.

This is the function where:

```
public function createUser($username, $password) {
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/shop/app/bootstrap.php';
    $_SERVER['username'] = $username;
    $_SERVER['password'] = md5($password);
    include 'CustomerApp.php';
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('CustomerApp');
    return $bootstrap->run($app);
  }
```

The Application injected in Bootstrap is:

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http as RequestHttp;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http as ResponseHttp;
use Magento\Framework\Event;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\App\AreaList;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;

class CustomerApp extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface {

protected $_customerInterface;
protected $_customInterface;
protected $customer_Repository;

protected $answer;

public function launch() {
    $answer = $this->insertCustomer();
    return $answer;
    //return $this->_response;
}

public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception) {
    return false;
}

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
 * @param Event\Manager $eventManager
 * @param AreaList $areaList
 * @param RequestHttp $request
 * @param ResponseHttp $response
 * @param ConfigLoaderInterface $configLoader
 * @param State $state
 * @param Filesystem $filesystem
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
 \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository $customer_Repository,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customerInterface
 */
public function __construct(
                              \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
                              Event\Manager $eventManager,
                              AreaList $areaList,
                              RequestHttp $request,
                              ResponseHttp $response,
                              ConfigLoaderInterface $configLoader,
                              State $state,
                              Filesystem $filesystem,
                              \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
                              \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository $customer_Repository,
                              \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customerInterface
) {
    $this->_objectManager         = $objectManager;
    $this->_eventManager          = $eventManager;
    $this->_areaList              = $areaList;
    $this->_request               = $request;
    $this->_response              = $response;
    $this->_configLoader          = $configLoader;
    $this->_state                 = $state;
    $this->_filesystem            = $filesystem;
    $this->registry               = $registry;
    $this->customer_Repository    = $customer_Repository;
    $this->_customerInterface     = $customerInterface;
}

public function insertCustomer() {
    $customer_1 = array(
            "email"=> "test@test.com",
            "firstname"=> 'John',
            "lastname"=> "Mateos",
            "middlename"=> "",
            "prefix"=> "",
            "suffix"=> "",
            "gender"=> 0,
            "storeId"=> 1,
            "taxvat"=> "",
            "websiteId"=> 1,
            "addresses" => array()
    );

    $customer = array("customer1" => $customer_1);

    $respuesta = '';
    foreach($customer as $customers) {
        try {
            foreach($customers as $key => $value) {
                $field = 'set' . $key;
                $this->_customerInterface->$field($value);
            }
            $this->customer_Repository->save($this->_customerInterface, $_SERVER['password']);
            $answer = 'Ok';

        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            $answer = 'Customer Exist';
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

All works fine but I do not know how can I get the response sent to **createUser** function, i mean, in case the user exist, it returns 'Customer Exist' and in case the customer is created, it returns 'Ok'.

The fact is that when I try to return $answer, it arise an error.

I have used **return $this->_response** but it returns nothing.

What should I do? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting approach using a custom application for this. You have by now probably noticed that your `insertCustomer()` method is not returning anything. Hence `$answer` is also null.